# Reading the sheet name of a .xls file with Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have got 30 files named Data1.xls to Data30.xls. In each file, there are two sheets I'm interested in. The first is called 'Ergebnisse' where I get the name of the second sheet, which is important to me. This sheet changes its name. My problem here is that I don't know how to tell Matlab to use the changing sheet name.

What i got so far:

```
liste = dir('*.xls');                  % how many files in the folder
liste=struct2cell(liste);              
liste=liste(1,:)';                      

for i=1:length(liste)                   % i=number of files
    filename=['Data' num2str(i) '.xls'];
    [num,txt,raw]=xlsread(filename,'Ergebnisse');
    sheet=txt(3,1);
    [num,txt,raw]=xlsread(filename,sheet); 
 end
```

The answer for sheet is 'T4_quer_3' which I would normally write into the next `xlsread` but it doesn't work.
Thanks for your help

Comment: please look in the workspace and tell su what value sheet has. does it happen to be cell1x1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need the cell txt(3,1), but its content. so either go for

```
sheet=txt{3,1};%notice the other brackets
```

or you go for

```
[num,txt,raw]=xlsread(filename,sheet{:}); %{:}content of a cell
```